# Creating a new text file that has specific information from two other text files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to merge two text files into one. For instance,

File 1

```
NAME 3
ATOM 1 4 0 0 0
```

File 2

```
3  3  
(INPUT) - Node Node 1
```

I would like the 3rd text file to look like this:

```
NAME 3            3  3
ATOM 1 4 0 0 0    (INPUT)-Node Node 1
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to merge these together?

This is what I have tried: `paste -d "\n" file1.txt.file2.txt` It didn't work.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? The example rows don't seem to have anything in common, so it's not clear what you're supposed to be doing to create your second file.

Comment: In addition to showing some attempt you have made... What should the 3rd file format look like?

Comment: @Blckknght...I do not know how to get started. That's the first thing. I tried playing around with some code from other questions, but I kept getting tracebacks.

Comment: @jdi...I want the 3rd text file to simply have the other two columns next to one another.

Comment: @JamdeJam: Post what you have tried and post your tracebacks.

Comment: import re
>>> infile = open ('trigonal3out_outJULY28two.txt', 'r')
>>> outfile = open('trigonal3out_outJULY28three.txt', 'w')
>>> column = 1
>>> for line in file:
 if not re.match('#', line):
  line = line.strip()
  sline = line.split()
  outfile.write(sline[column] + '\n')

  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#69>", line 1, in <module>
    for line in file:
NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Comment: Edit it into your question, so you'll have formatting options. It's impossible to understand when it's in a comment.

Comment: I re-edited the question and put the error in there.

Comment: I cannot put the error in the edit. It won't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

That could work:

```
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
    lines = [line_f1.strip() + line_f2.strip() for line_f1, line_f2 in zip(f1, f2)]

with open(file3, 'w') as f3:
    for line in lines:
        f3.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: That didn't work either. :/. It said that my file 1 wasn't defined.

Comment: You have to replace `file1`, `file2` and `file3` by the local path of each text file.